# .NET ContentInfo taking too long to process

Tags: c#, .net, security

The following code using ContentInfo(System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.ContentInfo) is really taking a long time to execute.

Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

```
byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName );
var contentInfo = new ContentInfo(fileContents);
var signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo);
signedCms.Decode(fileContents);
signedCms.RemoveSignature(0);
```

Comment: if it's hanging your app, you should put it in another thread.  I'm not sure how you can speed up the actual function though...

Comment: Have to keep it in the executing thread because its in a high volume loop

Comment: @JL: I thought you knew that `ContentInfo` has nothing to do with C# - it's from .NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my situation - I figured out the problem, it was only taking too long during a debug session, outside of the VS debugger, the operation performed at normal acceptable speeds.